# Use string to call function method?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert a string value to a variable in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1893277/how-to-convert-a-string-value-to-a-variable-in-javascript)

In Javascript, I have an object that looks like this:

```
clock = function(){
    this.load = function(){
        alert("once");
    }

    this.once = function(){
        alert("load");
    }
}
var clock =  new clock();
```

On the page load, I call the `load()` function within the clock object like so

```
clock.load();
```

When the user clicks a link, however, I need to be able to run `clock.once()`. Calling it like this is fine, but does not fit the dynamic needs of what I'm doing.

Let's say I need to call `clock.once()` when the user clicks an `<a>` tag:

```
$("a").click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr("href").match(/[a-zA-Z]+/g);
    [id].once();
}
```

I figured that would work, where the object that the `once()` function is being called from is grabbed from the string `id`.

When running this, however, I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object clock has no method 'once'

Manually calling `once()` by using `clock.once()` works fine.

Comment: Really haven't given enough information. Obviously you have more than one instance of "clock", and if not, why not just repeat the call with `clock.once()`? Why not have `once` accept the id argument?

Comment: Why the downvote? I didn't realize not knowing something was considered bad.

Comment: @Charlie: I think you were downvoted for how your question is formulated (it should provide more information), not for what you are asking.

Comment: @Andre Honestly I thought it was formatted fine. That's what my code looks like. There is only one instance of `clock`, but when a person clicks a link that has a different `href` attribute, it needs to run the `once()` function within the `id` object (that is the same as the `href` attr clicked, they are always the same).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[id].once` is not not going to work because you aren't referencing a particular array that you've created that contains clock objects.  You would need a particular array where you had stored multiple instances of clock objects (if you had constructed the proper array).

If you had previous create an array of clock objects:

```
var clocks = [];
clocks.push(new clock());
clocks.push(new clock());
```

Then, you could index into that particular array like this assuming id was a valid index into that array:

```
clocks[id]
```

If you're really just asking how to convert a string to a number, you can do that several ways.  Here are two common ways:

```
parseInt(id, 10)
+id
```

Comment: It's valid syntax, but `.once` does not exist of course.

Comment: @FelixKling - OK, I've modified my wording, but you get the point.  It isn't code that is going to work in this context.